# Preview rendering the current view from the viewport?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

How can the current viewport view be rendered as a preview?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## Blender 2.8+

This is now accomplished with the fully interactive *Rendered* viewport shading mode.

Click the rightmost sphere icon in the top right of the 3D viewport to enter *Rendered* mode, which displays the scene (more or less) exactly as it will be rendered:

[image: Viewport shading modes]

Alternatively, hit <kbd>Z</kbd> and select the *Rendered* mode from the *Shading* pie menu:

[image: Shading mode pie menu]

To remove any overlays, outlines, or gizmos covering up parts of the rendered view, turn off *Gizmos* and *Overlays* by clicking the icons beside the dropdown arrows left of the shading mode:

[image: Gizmos and Overlays]

---

## Blender 2.69 – 2.79

Use the key combination <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to switch to *Rendered* mode. Hit the key combination again to return to *Solid* mode. Alternatively, switch the *Viewport Shading* mode between the white sphere (*Solid*) and pink sphere (*Rendered*) in the 3D Viewport header/footer bar.

[image: Render mode selection menu]

This lacks viewport overlays, however, so it will be difficult to work in fully rendered mode. Nonetheless, it is possible to pivot the view and look around.

---

## Blender 2.68 and Earlier

Switch the *Viewport Shading* mode between *Solid* and *Rendered* as described in the section above. However, the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut is not bound by default in earlier versions of the software. But you can bind it yourself:

Open the User Preferences (*File* > *User Preferences...*) and switch to the *Input* tab. From the expandable list, locate *3D View* and expand it, then also expand *3D View (Global)* immediately below.

[image: User Settings > Input > 3D View > 3D View (Global)]

Scroll to the bottom of the expanded list and you will find an *Add New* button.

[image: Add New button at the bottom of the expanded list]

Click *Add New*, then expand the new entry entitled "none".

[image: Add New button and its expanded new unbound keymap]

With the new, unbound keymap entry expanded:

- Replace `none` with `wm.context_toggle_enum` which should lead to three new text fields appearing beneath.
- Bind the *Z* key by clicking the key field (contains the default *A*) and press <kbd>Z</kbd>.
- Check the *Shift* keyboard modifier checkbox.
- Fill the new three values, starting with `space_data.viewport_shade` for *Context Attribute*.
- Next, enter `SOLID` for *Value 1* (beneath *Context Attribute*).
- Finally, enter `RENDERED` for *Value 2* (right of *Context Attribute*).

[image: Values filled in for the full keymap]

To save these changes for future use, click *Save User Settings* at the footer of the User Preferences window which will update the startup file with the currently open one that now includes the added keymap. Make sure this is a clean startup file.

[image: User Settings footer with Save User Settings button]

Comment: Note: this will not use any compositing you may have.

Comment: Note: this shortcut was added in 2.69. For older versions you can setup this shortcut manually.

Answer (score 22):

### **Rendering the Current View**

The easiest way to do this is this:

1. Set the camera's view to your current viewport's view:
   <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>
2. Then render the image with one of these methods:

   - Info header -> Render -> Render Image
   - Object Properties window -> Render tab -> Render section -> click the Render button

You can read more about rendering in Blender [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render) on the Blender Wiki.

Comment: Useful for doing an actual render, but the purpose of this question was to make people aware of *Shift + Z* to preview render the current view.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you only wanted to talk about the Rendered View mode for the 3D Viewport.

Comment: It's a useful answer if people are looking to do a real render so you may want to label the answer as such and keep it.

Comment: If you don't want the camera to permanently move to your current view, make sure to keyframe it first.

Comment: Or make another temporary camera. Or just use *Ctrl + Z* after rendering to undo it. Not to be confused with *Shift + Z*, the other solution.

Comment: I don't have a NUMPAD, my keyboard is small, how do I do step 1 without a NUMPAD!

Answer (score 4):

For people using a custom input setup (I'm using the packed-in 3ds max settings with a few modifications) the keyboard shortcut alone isn't very useful. For anyone wanting to find, change, or add these settings in `File -> User Preferences -> Input`, their names and values are:

For "*Quickly previewing the current view*" (Shift Z): **Toggle Rendered Shading**
(in `3D View -> 3D View (Global)` with the value `view3d.toggle_render`)

For "*Rendering the current view*" (Ctrl Alt Numpad0): **Align Camera To View**
(in `3D View -> 3D View (Global)` with the value `view3d.camera_to_view`)