# In blender 3.6 after selecting the Light > Sun why I can't switch to edit mode?

Tags: objects, edit-mode, selection-tools

Either if I'm selecting the parent sun or it's child sun in both cases when pressing the tab key nothing happens. I also tried in the drop-down menu and there is no edit mode.

I can switch to edit mode of example if I select one of the airplane parts.

I want to select the sun and to be able to rotate the sun around and for that if I'm not mistaken, I need the sun to be in edit mode.

[image: Selected the sun but I can't rotate the sun and can't change to edit mode.]

Comment: Lamp objects, cameras and empties don't have an edit mode. You don't need to be in edit mode to rotate objects, you can rotate them in object mode.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos what does he do in this tutorial in minute 1:04 ? it looks like he change the sun but when I'm selecting the sun and changing the values in the transform of the rotation or position nothing happens the sun rotate but nothing change in the light view like in the video.  i also tried it on the Light but nothing.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhcOrnnc6YY

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view-editor/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/preview-rendering-the-current-view-from-the-viewport/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123164/what-is-lookdev-material-preview-mode-for-in-2-8

Comment: i found how to do it thanks.